# Asymptotic rate of decay of the integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals, asymptotics, mathematical-physics

For each $n$ define the sequence $y_n= \int_{0}^\infty (1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}})^n e^{-x}dx$. By dominated convergence theorem, it is clear that $y_n$ converges to $0$. I am interested in finding the rate at which $y_n$ decays. Mainly I am interested to know if the decay is exponential in $n$ or not i.e $y_n$ is roughly $c^n$ for some n ?

I have encountered this in a physics problem. I am unsure how to study the asymptotic behaviour. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got (confirmed numerically) $$y_n=e^{-2\sqrt{\ln n}}\left(1-\frac\gamma{\sqrt {\ln n}}+\frac{\gamma^2+\pi^2/6}{2\ln n}+O\Big(\,\frac1{\ln^{3/2}n}\,\Big)\right)$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT.** After reading **@Zarrax**'s answer, I realized that my original, heuristic guess cannot hold true. Below is a new answer.

---

Performing integration by parts,

$$ y_n = \frac{n}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2/4} (1 - e^{-x^2/4})^{n-1} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then, applying the substitution $y = e^{-x^2/4}$ (i.e., $x = 2\sqrt{\log(1/y)}$) followed by $y = t/n$, we get

\begin{align*}
y_n
&= n \int_{0}^{1} (1-y)^{n-1} e^{-2\sqrt{\log(1/y)}} \, \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int_{0}^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} e^{-2\sqrt{\log n - \log t}} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Using this, we prove:

> $$ \bbox[color:blue; padding:8px; border:1px dotted navy;]{ y_n = e^{-2\sqrt{\log n}}(1 + o(1)) } $$

**Lower bound.** Assume that $n \geq 2$. Noting that $\sqrt{1+x} \leq 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ for all $x \geq -1$, we get

\begin{align*}
y_n
&\geq \int_{0}^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} e^{-2\sqrt{\log n} + \frac{\log t}{\sqrt{\log n}}} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e^{-2\sqrt{\log n}} \biggl( \int_{0}^{n} t^{1/\sqrt{\log n}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr)
\end{align*}

To analyze the asymptotic behavior of this lower bound, we use the inequality $1 + x \leq e^{-x}$ to find that

$$ t^{1/\sqrt{\log n}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)_+^{n-1}
\leq (1 + t) e^{-t/2} $$

for all $t \in [0, n]$ and $n \geq 2$. So by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \int_{0}^{n} t^{1/\sqrt{\log n}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}t
\to \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t = 1. $$

This shows that

$$ \color{blue}{ y_n \geq e^{-2\sqrt{\log n}}(1 + o(1)). } $$

**Upper bound.** Noting that $\sqrt{1+x} \geq 1 + \frac{x}{2+x}$ for all $x \geq -1$, we get

\begin{align*}
y_n
&\leq \int_{0}^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} e^{-2\sqrt{\log n} ( 1 - \frac{\log t}{2\log n - \log t})} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e^{-2\sqrt{\log n}} \biggl( \int_{0}^{n} t^{\frac{2\sqrt{\log n}}{2\log n - \log t}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr)
\end{align*}

Arguing similarly as before, we find that

$$ t^{\frac{2\sqrt{\log n}}{2\log n - \log t}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1}
\leq (1 + t)e^{-t/2} $$

for all $t \in [0, n]$ and $n \geq 2$, hence by the dominated convergence theorem

$$\int_{0}^{n} t^{\frac{2\sqrt{\log n}}{2\log n - \log t}} \left( 1 - \frac{t}{n} \right)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}t
\to \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t
= 1. $$

Therefore

$$ \color{blue}{ y_n \leq e^{-2\sqrt{\log n}}(1 + o(1)). } $$

Answer (score 8):

The $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^n$ factor starts becoming relevant when $e^{-{x^2 \over 4}}$ is about ${1 \over n}$, since then $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^n
= (1 - {1 \over n})^n \sim {1 \over e}$. In fact, for large enough $n$, $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^n > {1 \over 2e}$ beyond that value of $x$. If you solve $e^{-{x^2 \over 4}} = {1 \over n}$ you obtain $x = 2\sqrt{\ln n}$, so for large $n$ your integral is at least

$${1 \over 2e} \int_{2 \sqrt{\ln n}}^{\infty} e^{-x}\,dx$$
$$= {1 \over 2e} e^{-2\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$$
This gives a lower bound for your integral, which shows it decays slower than any polynomial or exponential power.

If you want to bound it above, it's a little trickier. But you can churn out the calculation to show that the derivative of $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^ne^{-x}$ is positive on $[0,2\sqrt{\ln{n}}]$. Thus your integral is at most $2\sqrt{\ln{n}}$ times the value of $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^ne^{-x}$ at $x = 2\sqrt{\ln{n}}$, which is of order $\sqrt{\ln{n}}\,e^{-2\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$.

So the overall rate of decay of your integral is somewhere between the orders of $e^{-2\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$ and $\sqrt{\ln{n}}\,e^{-2\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$.
My guess would be it is $O(e^{-2\sqrt{\ln{n}}})$.

If you want to get more refined asymptotics I'd suggest trying to see what Laplace's method gives you. Your domain of integration is unbounded but sometimes that method will still work.

Comment: (+1) Awesome! Reading this, I was able to realize that my original guess about the asymptotic behavior of $y_n$ cannot hold and correct the errors.

Comment: @SangchulLee Your answer was what I expected to be true because the function $(1 - e^{-{x^2 \over 4}})^n$ decreases so fast when $x$ decreases below $2 \sqrt{\ln n}$, and it's nice to see you were able to show these asymptotics do in fact hold.

Answer (score 6):

$$y_n= \int_{0}^\infty \Big(1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}})\Big)^n e^{-x}dx$$ $$y_n=1+ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \,\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{k x^2}{4}-x}\,dx$$
$$y_n=1+\sqrt \pi \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \,\binom{n}{k}\,\frac{e^{\frac{1}{k}}\,
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$

*I am stuck at this point for the asymptotics.*

Comment: Using naive curve-fitting to assess the rate at which a sequence tends to 0 seems somewhat dubious. The function you have cooked up will in fact tend to $-\infty$, since $c > 0$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler. Sorry, I used the wrong data. One more stupid mistake !